# Return one row when multiples are returned

Tags: sql-server, duplicates

Firstly apologies for this as a number of similar posts have been posted but I just can't seem to return what I would like

My data returns

```
desc | date | taken | result | text | notes | page | group | q | answer | value | state | time |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Asess1 | 20170101 | John | 5 | Injury | xxx | Page1 | Assess11 | 1 | 1234567 | 1 | 1 | 0 |  
Asess1 | 20170101 | John | 5 | Injury | xxx | Page1 | Assess11 | 1 | 1234567 | 1 | 1 | 0 |  
Asess1 | 20170101 | John | 5 | Injury | xxx | Page1 | Assess11 | 1 | 1234567 | 1 | 1 | 0 |  
Asess1 | 20170101 | John | 5 | Injury | xxx | Page1 | Assess11 | 1 | 1234567 | 1 | 1 | 0 |  
Asess1 | 20170101 | John | 5 | Injury | xxx | Page1 | Assess11 | 1 | 1234567 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
```

Code as follows

```
select t.desc,a.date,a.taken,a.result,a.text,a.notes,d.page,d.group,d.q,d.answer,d.value,d.state,d.timeSpanSeconds
from cc_clientAssessments a
inner join cs_assessmentData d on a.assessmentId=d.assessment
inner join cs_clients c on c.person=a.residentId
inner join cs_facilities f on f.guid=a.facilityId
inner join cs_assessmentTypes t on t.assessmentTypeId=a.assessmentTypeId

where c.surname='smith'
and f.name='home'
and t.description ='injury'
and a.dateTaken='2017-05-28 00:00:00.000'
and d.questionName='1'
and d.answer='1234567'
order by t.desc, a.date desc,d.page,d.group,d.q
```

any help would be great.

Comment: Since they all are same so you can use `DISTINCT` clause.

Comment: [DISTINCT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187831(v=sql.105).aspx) could be what you are looking for - you should include the desired result.

Comment: I think you need to comment out the joins and then add them one by one until you find which table has more than 1 corresponding row. A distinct would solve it for the moment, but that's maybe not the best solution if you don't know what the issue is.

Comment: To add on to @RigertaDemiri comment, you should do a `select * ` on your query to see full data and then figure out what repeats.

Comment: Thanks all should have mentioned I tried distinct however, it does not work as The text data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.

Comment: Did you tried `SELECT TOP (1)`?

Comment: Thanks TOP(1)  will work for the one record however when I run it on a full set of data (ie removing some of the criteria) it unfortunately wont have the desired effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One (or more) of your `join`s is causing this duplication, because you have not been specific enough in your `join` criteria.

As other commenters have said, remove all your `join`s and then add them back in one by one until you start to see duplicates.  Using `select *` you can see what additional data is being pulled back and therefore what additional filters you need to include in that `join`.  Once you have no duplication, add in the next `join` and repeat the whole process.

This is the sensible way to resolve this as nine times out of ten you *can* stop this duplication with more specific `join` criteria, which will also ensure your query is processing less data and will therefore be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Although the elegant solution is to fix your joins so they don't result in as many rows, a very quick fix would be to just use **distinct** to eliminate duplicates and convert your text field to an string, so it can be compared.

```
select distinct t.desc,a.date,a.taken,a.result,substring(a.text,1,512) as text,a.notes,d.page,d.group,d.q,d.answer,d.value,d.state,d.timeSpanSeconds
from cc_clientAssessments a
inner join cs_assessmentData d on a.assessmentId=d.assessment
inner join cs_clients c on c.person=a.residentId
inner join cs_facilities f on f.guid=a.facilityId
inner join cs_assessmentTypes t on t.assessmentTypeId=a.assessmentTypeId

where c.surname='smith'
and f.name='home'
and t.description ='injury'
and a.dateTaken='2017-05-28 00:00:00.000'
and d.questionName='1'
and d.answer='1234567'
order by t.desc, a.date desc,d.page,d.group,d.q
```

Comment: This answer solves the symptom, but not the problem.  It is lazy coding that results in inefficient queries and future headaches.